# How to get a value from a selected row in jfxtreetableview

Tags: javafx, jfoenix

I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find any easy way to get selected value from a jfxtreetableview like good old jtable anyone knows about it?

I have created a jfxtreetableview and populated data.

```
JFXTreeTableColumn<Person, String> address = new JFXTreeTableColumn("Address"); 
address.setPrefWidth(100); 
address.impl_setReorderable(false); 
address.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() 
{ 
@Override public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) 
{ 
return param.getValue().getValue().address; 
} 
});
```

Comment: Post your attempt.

Comment: I have created a jfxtreetableview and populated data.

  JFXTreeTableColumn<Person, String> address = new JFXTreeTableColumn("Address");
        address.setPrefWidth(100);
        address.impl_setReorderable(false);
        address.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) {
                return param.getValue().getValue().address;
            }
        });

Comment: Edit your question with this new information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get selected item by doing this :

```
yourTreeTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Thanx man! actually yourTreeTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() worked for me!